# How to find the definition of an automatically inferred VB type in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

In Visual Studio (2015):

- In C#, if you put the cursor on the keyword `var` and press <kbd>F12</kbd> it takes you to the definition of whatever type it has figured out for your variable.

but...

- In VB, if you put the cursor on the keyword `Dim` when you are using `Option Infer` and press <kbd>F12</kbd> it says "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret."

I was surprised this didn't work, since my understanding is that these two cases are nearly equivalent.

Since that doesn't work for VB, **is there some other way to get to the definition of the inferred type?**

Note that when used in conjunction with `Option Infer On`, a VB variable declaration without a type specified is an inferred type - just like in C# where the 'var' keyword is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB, you get the type information for an inferred type by either hovering over the 'Dim' or over the variable name.

C# also shows you the inferred type information in one additional way - F12 on the 'var' keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Below fix worked for me

```
 1. devenv.exe /resetuserdata

 2. Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols -> Empty Symbol Cache
```

[Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48280583/3725288)