# VS2017 not showing suggestions & cannot navigate to the symbol under caret

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

My Visual Studio is having some problems:

Suddenly it stopped showing any useful suggestions.
`artikelList` contains `articles` with many properties but all it shows is this:

[image]

Additionally, when I try to go to the implementation of a method via `ctrl+f12` it shows the following error message:

[image]

I've tried to restart VS17, restart my pc, reset the settings and reinstall VS17 but it didn't help.

Has anyone had these problems as well and knows how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: Try any of these solutions: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-resolve-intellisense-issue-in-visual-studio1. Ps: if you create a new project, will it still won't appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was something with my user data... I don't know what exactly but resetting it together with a "clear symbols" fixed the issues:

1. `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`
2. `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols -> Empty Symbol Cache`

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me just on one project , just deleting .vs file worked for me